# ASP.Net MVC Web API JavaScriptSerializer - Byte Array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that is returning some info along with a image (byte array)

```
var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Snippet:

```
{"CompanyName":"MyCompany","Address":"Address1","Logo":"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"}
```

So when I try to map

```
var profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<WebApi.Common.DomainObjects.WebProfile>(result);

 public class WebProfile
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
    }
```

I get this error:
Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

If anyone could provide an example of how to resolve would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Frank, I ended up Just creating a new property.

```
 public byte[] Logo
        {
            get { return Convert.FromBase64String(LogoString); }
        }

public string LogoString { get; set; }
```